# What are the best practices for providing a client with brand assets?

Tags: branding

I have created a logo for a client and don't know the best way to give the file to the client. What are the best file types to provide the client, eg illustrator, Photoshop, jpeg, TIFF and what document sizes would be best.

An example:
The TIFF file I have created is 9035 x 9448 pixels, as the object I created the print for was about 800mm high by 750mm wide. The file size is (understandably) 405MB. This doesn't seem appropriate as the PDF file will do the job just fine and is just 100kb as the original artwork is a vector.

What would the standard or general guideline be creating a brand asset for any eventual use?

Comment: Hi Aasim Azam, can I ask why you are working with a vector file that is so large? Are the files for proofs or for final artwork? I usually export as PDF for proofs.

Comment: The order actually began with "can you Vectorise 'this' and print it 800mm x 750mm and then the order became give me the files as a logo

Comment: You should be fine with a PDF. You can always ask the printer if they have any specifications for exporting the document.

Comment: The Roland printer I have access to loves TIFF files and just eats them up. PDFs however have provided to be a little troublesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I create a logo for a client I provide them with the following:

- **Greyscale/1 color** (300ppi) (may be 2 versions - 1 solid black, the other greys)
  Tiff, PSD, EPS, AI, PDF
- **CMYK** (300ppi)
  Tiff, PSD, EPS, AI, PDF
- **Spot Color** (300ppi) (provided if appropriate)
  Tiff, PSD, EPS, AI, PDF
- **RGB** (72ppi)
  PSD, EPS, AI, SVG, PDF, JPG, PNG24, GIF (only because some may expect it)
- **Usage guidelines** (PDF) -- Detailing spacing, color, size, requirements/suggestions - "Dos" and "Donts"

Most often I'll size things to around 500x500px or relatively close to that. So all the above are basically the same size, just varying in color and resolution.

I wouldn't ever provide a 9000x9000px file to a client for a logo. They'll be lost with something that size in most cases.

This seems like a lot, right? It is somewhere between 17 and 28 separate files just for their logo

My goal is to *never* have the client contact me again for a format they need for their logo. Not because I don't want to hear from them, but because I want them to have *every possible format* they'll ever need for the logo.  For me, this is *why* clients want a professional creating their logo - providing a *complete* solution rather than merely sending them a JPG they'll need to have reworked in a couple years when they realize that $5 logo isn't going to work for everything.

Comment: The artwork I created was not supposed to be a logo, it was just for printing, but it turned out my client liked it so much that he decided it needs to be a logo. But I don't know if I was thinking right when I exported the tiff so big. But your answer helps a lot. I'll wait a couple of days before marking the answer to garner more responses. That isnt to say your answer didn't cover everything or warrant the mark. Also note the level of client I'm working with now is much more discerning than my previous ones and I am kind of a newb

Comment: Just be sure to price for logo development as well though :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually ask the client what they need. If they don't know, then I typically provide:

- PDF
- SVG
- PNG (large and small versions)

There's no particular standard, though. It depends on the particular client and the particular logo.